# Is it possible to apply a gpo that will prevent from adding more than one account in any browser or only letting to login with a domain email

Tags: windows, server, windows-server-2019

Is there a way through Group Policy to sort out how users interact with web browsers? I'm wondering if it's possible to set things up so that users can't add more than one account and are limited to logging in with their domain email addresses. I want to make sure this applies consistently across different browsers without causing too much frustration for users. Are there any specific challenges or things to watch out for in getting this set up? Also, what's the best way to test it out before rolling it out widely? I'd appreciate any insights on documentation or support channels to consult, and how adaptable these settings are to future changes in browsers or updates.

I did try to find for solution on other forums , however it seems that , it is not possible with the help of gpo , so was wondering if there is any other way.